# Add text input to Pikaday modal dialog

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom, pikaday

I am trying to redesign [Pikaday](http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/), and replace the year select to a text input.
However, whenever I am adding an input there - it becomes disabled. If I inspect this element - it is not disabled, not z-indexed to background and not with opacity. Just not clicable. On hover, however, it does replace the cursor to text-edit cursor.

Does anyone know why it happens, and whether it is available to "fix" it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after analyzing the code better - I saw that all the modal dialog is listening to an event on mouse down - that "preventDefault"s it whenever the click is not on an expected target. [image: The guilty method].

So, in my case, just applying class 'pika-select' will make the form element to be interacted as expected.